# VBA: Compare two cells (they could contain spaces)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a for loop with 10'000 elements which is looped 20, 30, 40 times.
And each time I compare two cells. Unfortunately, they could both contain a space at the end. So I cannot just code like this:

```
            'If article no or name fits with supplier, size and colour
        If (wsC.Cells(i, 47).Value = SearchForNameSupplier _
            Or wsC.Cells(i, 15).Value = SearchForArticleSupplier) And _
            wsC.Cells(i, 18).Value = Supplier And _
            wsC.Cells(i, 49).Value = Size And _
            wsC.Cells(i, 50).Value = Color Then
            wsB.Cells(z, 14).Value = wsC.Cells(i, 1).Value 'Aricle
            wsB.Cells(z, 15).Value = wsC.Cells(i, 14).Value 'Price
            wsB.Cells(z, 11).Value = wsC.Cells(i, 48).Value 'Name
        End If
```

When I trim all these cells, excel shuts down!! How could I solve this?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Why are you looping so many times? That's your problem.

Comment: what's the rest of your loop look like? It shouldn't take that many loops to get through.

Comment: Hi Guys. I have one sheet with article numbers. There are at the moment "just" 10'000. In the other sheet I enter some article numbers. The loop now checks if these article numbers are in the big list and if yes, the name of the article number with be copied from the big list to the small list.